# SQL update where value in other table is

Tags: sql

I need to update a value in a table if a specific value exists in another table.

i.e.

```
update table1 
set value1=3 
where table2.value2='Y'
```

There is a key `ref1` in both tables- how do i use this key to link these together? Many thanks!

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table1 
inner join table2 on table1.ref1 = table2.ref1
set value1 = 3
where table2.value2 = 'Y'
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Oracle. Oracle complains about "missing SET keyword" at the end of line 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a join between both tables and then make the update from the join.

Something like:

```
update tableA  
set column = b.value
from tableA a
     join tableB on a.key = b.key
```